# Using variables from other files calling it by using variables

Tags: python

This is my code for file_1:

```py
type_Of_word = [
    'movies',
    'animals',
    'characters'
]

movies = [
    'Thor',
    'Tangled',
    'Forzen',
    'Spider-Man: No Way Home'
]

animals = [
    'Zebra',
    'Porcupine'
]

characters = [
    'Mickey Mouse',
    'Loki Odinson'
]
```

And my code for file_2:

```py
import random
import gile_1

word = None

def get_word():
    type_of_word_choice = random.choice(file_1.type_Of_word)
    global word
    word = random.choice(file_1.type_Of_word_choice)
    print(word)
```

What I want to do is to use the name of the type stored in 'type_of_word_choice' and call the specific variable with the list of names and get the random choice of word.

But when I run this, it tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aisha\.codeVS\hangman\firstHangman.py", line 95, in <module>
    get_word()
  File "c:\Users\aisha\.codeVS\hangman\firstHangman.py", line 9, in get_word
    word = random.choice(words.type_Of_word_choice)
AttributeError: module 'words' has no attribute 'type_Of_word_choice'
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: The part where it says words is supposed to say file_1

Comment: Don't use separate lists, use a dict, where `movies`, `animals` and `characters` would be keys.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70161739/edit) button if you need to update your question

Comment: `type_Of_word_choice` isn't defined in file 1 (which I assume is named `words.py`)

Comment: Is `file_1`'s name really `words.py`? If so, please [edit] your question and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Define your words as a nested dictionary structure.

```
words = {
    'movies': [
        'Thor',
        'Tangled',
        'Frozen',
        'Spider-Man: No Way Home'
    ],
    'animals': [
        'Zebra',
        'Porcupine'
    ],
    'characters': [
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Loki Odinson'
    ]
}
```

Then write your code to first choose a random category, then a word from that category.

```
def get_word():
    type_of_word = random.choice(list(words))
    word = random.choice(words[type_of_word])
    return word

print(get_word())
```

Comment: I'd personally use this option instead of defining categories as variables in the global namespace :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr` to dynamically get your second list (movies, animals or characters).

```
import random
import words

def get_word():
    type_of_word_choice = random.choice(words.type_Of_word)
    word = random.choice(getattr(words, type_of_word_choice))
    return word

word = get_word()
print(word)

# Output sample
Mickey Mouse
```

**Note**: don't use `global` variables. If you call a function return a value to set your variable.

Comment: using `getattr` like this is rarely good practise also